# send xml file on get request ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, http

I want to send an XML file when get request is made

here is my my xml file

```
<forms>
<form url="https://opendatakit.appspot.com/formXml?formId=CascadingSelect">Cascading Select Form</form>
<form url="https://opendatakit.appspot.com/formXml?formId=widgets">Widgets</form>
</forms>
```

this is my url

```
http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist
```

here is my ruby controller to send a xml

```
respond_to :xml
def formlist
   respond_to do |format|
     format.xml {//what should I write here to send formlist.xml}
   end
end
```

here is route.rb

```
get 'forms/formlist' => 'forms#formlist'
```

but its not sending xml file giving error code something 422

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add `.xml` to url: http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist.xml
2. Then simply render your file:

   `def formlist
      respond_to do |format|
        format.xml { render '/path/to/formlist.xml' }
      end
   end`
3. Instead of adding .xml to url you can write your route as this:

   `get 'forms/formlist' => 'forms#formlist', defaults: { format: 'xml' }`

   so every request without MIME type will be interpreted as xml request

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   format.xml {//what should I write here to send formlist.xml}
> end
> ```

You don't have to write anything between the braces--if your xml file has the correct name.

#### The route:

First, your route can be simply:

```
get "forms/formlist"
```

By default, rails assumes that a route has the format `controller/action`.

#### The action:

Your formlist() action can simply look like this:

```
 def formlist
    respond_to :xml  
 end
```

The `respond_to` line is a shortcut for:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.xml {}
end
```

In either case, your action will only respond to requests for an xml file; requests for other file types will produce an UnknownFormat error.

#### The view:

Then create the xml file here:

```
app/views/forms_controller/formlist.xml.erb
```

If you don't have any ruby code in your xml file, you can omit the .erb extension.

#### The url:

To request the xml file, you can use the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist
```

...and specify the following header in the request:

```
Accept: text/xml
```

For instance:

```
curl --header 'Accept: text/xml' http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist
```

Or, as rubykid posted, you can use the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist.xml
```

For instance:

```
 curl http://localhost:3000/forms/formlist.xml
```

In either case, rails understands that the request is asking for an xml file.

#### respond_to():

By default, an action renders an html file named:

```
app/views/some_controller/action_name.html.erb
```

The default rendering can be changed with `respond_to()` and/or `render()`.

For example, `respond_to :xml` will render the file:

```
app/views/some_controller/action_name.xml.erb
```

...which in your case will be:

```
app/views/forms_controller/formslist.xml.erb
```

If you want to render a different xml file, only then do you need to use the *block form* of respond_to() and write something inside the braces:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.xml {render ...}
end
```

In that case, see the [Rails Guide on rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) for what you can do with render().

For completeness sake, the shortcut:

```
respond_to :xml, :json
```

...is equivalent to:

```
respond to do |format|
  format.xml {}
  format.json {}
end
```

#### Another option:

If the xml file is a static file, i.e. its content never changes, and you want to make it publicly available to anybody, you can put it in the `public/` folder.  For instance, if you name the xml file:

```
public/data.xml
```

...then anyone can request the xml file with the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/data.xml
```